# Knockout Kendo Grid dataBound events

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I have a kendo ui grid using the [knockout-kendo](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/) set.

I have a few custom buttons in one column of the grid i.e. to make a ajax call for edit a entry in another div, delete one or check for an editId to call a function. My problem is, **that both events fired twice**! Besides for me it looks like `dataBound` event and `dataBinding` event is the same.

Heres a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXn7e/40/)

```
this.dataBound = function(){
    alert('dataBound');
};

this.dataBinding = function(){
    alert('dataBinding');
};
```

I tried some different approaches.

Heres another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXn7e/42/)

```
this.gridConfig = {
    data: self.myData,
    datasource: {
        data: 'data'
    },
    dataBound: function(){
        alert('dataBound');
    },
    dataBinding: function(){
        alert('dataBinding');
    },
};
```

Events are fired when the grid is bound, and when the data is bound.
But how can I get sure, to get only an Event when all data is there?

Does anyone know whats going on there? BTW I using the mapping plugin.

Comment: I posted a response below. It does change the format of your code a bit in order to achieve what you want. If you have any specific questions around how to get it to work within your current setup, please let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `dataBound` event is firing for different reasons. The first time it fires, if you `console.log()` the event, you will see that:

- `e.sender._data` is an empty array `[]`
- `e.element[0]` is `div.k-grid.k-widget`

When the event fires for a second time, the same properties show as:

- `e.sender._data` is an array of length three, containing items like: `{ color: "green", name: "apple", uid: "..." }`
- `e.element[0]` is `div.k-grid.k-widget` (same element)

Which seems to imply that your grid is in-fact binding data to itself twice.

If I had to guess, KO's `ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());` initializes the object and triggers the event. Afterwards, the event is fired again when kendo attempts to bind the elements data internally.

To avoid this, see: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound

Where you could employ something similar to:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.bind("dataBinding", grid_dataBinding);
grid.dataSource.fetch();
```

When the initial config binding is set to `autoBind: false`

So that you don't accidentally catch that first *false* dataBound event.

If I have time, I'll make my way back with a JSFiddle that demonstrates this.

**Solution 1:** This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXn7e/44/) should help.

**Solution 2:**

Set `autoBind: false` so that the grid doesn't auto-bind. (@jason9187)

As another user mentioned, you can turn the initial auto-bind off by changing a setting that is mentioned in the above telerik documentation:

Basically, this fix in your first approach:

`<div id="grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: myData, dataBinding: dataBinding, dataBound: dataBound }"></div>`

Becomes:

`<div id="grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: { data: myData, dataBinding: dataBinding, dataBound: dataBound, autoBind: false }"></div>`

Or by adding the same property to your second approach.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hXn7e/45/

Comment: Okay, thanks very much for this! My setup is very complicated, the file got about 1600 lines... But in fact it seems that the simple line * autoBind: false * fix my problem ...

Answer (score 5):

Set `autoBind: false` so that the grid doesn't auto-bind.

```
this.gridConfig = {
    data: self.myData,
    autoBind : false,
    datasource: {
        data: 'data'
    },
    dataBound: function(){
        alert('dataBound');
    },
    dataBinding: function(){
        alert('dataBinding');
    },
};
```

Comment: simple, but it seems to fix this problem! sorry about that :-/

Comment: it's all about sharing information and helping each other out :)